# Change Boot drive in SeaBios

Tags: kvm-virtualization, boot, bios, virtio

I need to copy my KVM machine for further update.
BUT our provider don't provide opportunity to copy a whole machine, just a hard drive. (virtio drive vda/vdb etc)

So, I made a new clean machine, attach old drive copy and now trying to replace main hard drive. Unfortunately, the provider also don't provide this function in iaas panel.

I can send ctrl+alt+del and see boot message. (img below)[image: active-cloud-sucks]

So - there is SeaBios and gPXE. 
I don't really understand how to use it and can't find any useful documentation.

Any help?

1. Shall I try to switch booting hard drives using SeaBios? How?
2. Maybe my whole approach is definetely wrong? What shall I do instead?

I tried to call bios settings or boot menu using esc button but I didn't get anything useful (second img)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the boot drive in SeaBios won't help you, as you can only select which of the already attached disk images the system will boot from. Problem is the image you want is not attached to the VM.

You need to find a way to attach another disk image to your VM. This can only be done from outside the VM, either by a web interface or some CLI command (e.g. `virsh`). Consult the docs and ask the support and if they really offer no way to do this, switch providers.

Comment: many thanks for answer!
I don't mention that I already attached old-drive and trying to switch boot from it from clean one